# JPA (Java Persistent API)/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning JPA and tried for some interview questions. And I found a question along with answer. But unable to understand, can anybody explain this. This is the question and answer:

Question:- Insert a record mechanism using JPA?

Answer:-

```
@Override  
@Transactional  
public void create(Category entity) throws MeetingAppDAOException {  
    try {  
         logger.info("Enter - create()");  
         super.create(entity);  
         logger.info("Exit - create()");  
    } catch (PersistenceException exception) {  
      logger.error("create()::REASON OF EXCEPTION=" + exception.getMessage(), e);  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the surrounding class (and most probably its parent class), it is hard to say.

Comment: I found this question as it is in many places.

Comment: Pasting a question mark behind a sentence doesn't make it a question.. 'Insert a record mechanism using JPA?'